# ASP.NET MVC 2 Use Ajax to reload a UserControl

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

is it possible to use Ajax with ASP.NET MVC 2 to reload a user control, pass along a new Model and have it update all the values that make use of this model without refreshing the rest of the site content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!

I have the following code in the Controller:

```
[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateDinner(FormCollection formValues)
{
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    Dinner Dinner = DinnerRepository.GetDinner(Convert.ToInt32(formValues["Date"]));
    return PartialView("DeclaratieWidget", Dinner);
  }
}
```

I have this code in my View:

```
<script src="<%= AppPathHelper.Url(Request.ApplicationPath, "/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= AppPathHelper.Url(Request.ApplicationPath, "/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateDinner", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Dinner" }))
  { %>
  <select id="Date" name="Date">
    <option value="<%= Dinner.Dinner_ID %>"><%= Dinner.Date.ToString("dddd d MMMM") %></option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />

<div id="avondeten">
  <% Html.RenderPartial("DeclaratieWidget", Model.Dinners[0]); %>
</div>
```

It works perfectly this way! :D

Comment: Congratulations on getting something working before I could respond; veel geluk!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and here is one way to do so:

You can call an action on a controller from ajax (jquery is what I use) and get the result.  To pass data up you provide parameter values to the $.ajax() call and rendering back you just render a partial with whatever viewmodel is appropriate to your partial.

To get the content displayed you just take the HTML result passed back to your $.ajax() call and, most commonly, replace the contents of a div with your HTML result.

Comment: Hi Tahbaza! Thanks for your quick reply! That sounds like something I would need!

Could you provide some sample code to illustrate this please? What would have to be in my View? My controller looks like this:
[Authorize, HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateAvondeten(FormCollection formValues)
{
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    Avondeten avondeten = avondetenRepository.GetAvondeten(Convert.ToInt32(formValues["Datum"]));
    return PartialView("DeclaratieWidget", avondeten);
  }
  else
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Foutmelding", "Home");
  }
}